# WIX XmlConfig action not running on patch rollback

Tags: installation, wix, uninstallation

I've got a component that runs a couple of XmlConfig actions: one on install and one on uninstall:

```
  <Component Id="machine.config.Update" Guid="573DF5B0-438D-498d-8919-C4B96835C1EF">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="[REGISTRYKEY]\Settings\[TITLE]" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
      <RegistryValue Action="write" Type="integer" Name="MACHINEMEMORYLIMIT" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <util:XmlConfig
      Id="CacheNode.memoryLimit.add"
      File="[WindowsFolder]\Microsoft.NET\[FRAMEWORKDIR]\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.Config"
      Action="create"
      ElementPath="/configuration/system.web/processModel"
      Name="memoryLimit"
      Node="value"
      On="install"
      Value="90" />
    <util:XmlConfig
      Id="CacheNode.memoryLimit.remove"
      File="[WindowsFolder]\Microsoft.NET\[FRAMEWORKDIR]\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.Config"
      Action="delete"
      ElementPath="/configuration/system.web/processModel"
      VerifyPath="/configuration/system.web/processModel"
      Name="memoryLimit"
      Node="value"
      On="uninstall" />
  </Component>
```

The component is part of a patch that I can install and roll back. The problem is that the uninstall action doesn't fire when I uninstall the patch. The odd part is that the same XmlConfig action does execute if I change it to be `On="install"`. I see that the registry key is properly removed on uninstall. Why isn't the XmlConfig action firing as well? I checked the logs and did not see any errors or explanation of why it didn't happen.

**Update:**
The XmlConfig action works when doing a full uninstall. Just not on a patch rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from the wix-users mailing list.

Rob Mensching:
"Adding custom actions in patches doesn't work out so well. Patches essentially apply transform to the existing MSI then repair the MSI. In the case of uninstalling a patch, the transform is removed and the MSI is repaired. Obviously, if the custom action is removed with the transform then it has no chance to run.

The Windows Installer does special magic to keep track of the state of the MSI before and after the transform so they can properly remove data."

They also talked about how there was a feature in MSI 4.5 that may let you do it but WIX needed to stay compatible with earlier versions and there were still some data storage problems around it.

So in short, custom actions on patch uninstall don't work in WIX.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified your sample (almost) as is, at it works fine. The problem can be in your FRAMEWORKDIR property. Make sure it is set on both Install and Uninstall correctly.

It might be the case that it falls back to its default value for Uninstall flow and the attribute is removed, but from another file.

Comment: From the uninstaller log: "MSI (s) (D4:B0) [15:49:19:561]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding FRAMEWORKDIR property. Its value is 'Framework64'." This is before the action would normally try to run.

Comment: (and Framework64 is the expected and correct directory here). Also it turns out that the action fires correctly on a full uninstall of the product. It just doesn't seem to run on a patch rollback.

Comment: Probably, the reason is in the way you create your patch... Do you reference any specific components to get into it or simply let it pick everything changed?

Comment: We use the UpgradeImage and TargetImage to create the patch. I believe it finds the components automatically. It seems like it's finding the component and rolling it back successfully. That's why the registry key for the component gets removed. It's just that the XmlConfig action doesn't happen on the rollback of that component.

Comment: Then I ran out of ideas... One last try - upgrade your WiX toolset to the latest available (RTM - if you're on 3.0, or latest weekly build - if you're on 3.5/3.6)

Comment: Upgrading to 3.6.1314 didn't help. :(

Comment: When it turns to patching, I can recommend 2 great blogs: Peter Marcu's (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pmarcu/archive/tags/wix/) and Heath Stewart (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/tags/wix/). I can recall one of them blogging about patch applying and how the system works in general, but I can't find the exact posts at first glance. Hope you'll find useful info for your case as well.